# jQuery .each() span.Title get .text() connect with "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Live Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var PushState, Current;
  
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest($('.page-breadcrumb')).length) {
            $(e.target).closest('li').nextAll().remove();
            PushState = $('.page-breadcrumb').children('li').each(function() {
                return $(this).children().find('span.Title').text();
            }).get().join("/");
            console.log(PushState);
            Current = $(e.target).closest('a').html();
            $(e.target).closest('li').remove();
            $('.page-breadcrumb').append(Current);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.page-bar {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:61px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb>li,
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb>li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #A3A3A3;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb>li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.page-bar .page-breadcrumb>li>i.fa-arrow-right {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="page-bar">
    <div class="page-breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span class="Title">Dashboard</span> </a>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <span class="Title">Account</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <span class="Title">Messages</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></li>
        <li></li>
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        <span class="Title">Compose</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Outcome

Dependant on where you click, the outcome is as follows (I clicked on 'Account'):

> [object HTMLLIElement]/[object HTMLLIElement]/[object HTMLLIElement]

---

### What I'm Trying To Achieve

1. If `$(e.target)` is `$('.page-breadcrumb li a')`

   - Initiate everything the script currently does
   - `PushState` should return (clicking on Messages example):

     - Dashboard/Account/Messages

---

### Questions

How do I return the text only of each `span.Title` connectings all with '/'?

Comment: Why aren't you placing your click event on `$('.page-breadcrumb li a')`? And if you click, for example, Account, your `PushState` should be `Dashboard/Account`, right?

Comment: Because the element is not present on page load.

Comment: Well, then how are you loading your element? I am asking this because you could leverage a promise or execute the script when the elements load.

Comment: At the moment ajax however this is just for now whereas I plan to change to PHP means. This is early stages at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `return` in each callback is causing you to loose the data .If you even have this

```
PushState = $('.page-breadcrumb').children('li').each(function() {
              return 0;
            }).get().join("/");
```

you would still be getting the same results because what you are getting is just the outer `<li>` elements .So instead of returning use some variable in which you can store the individual results of `each`s callback

Make some global like variable `var v =[];` outside `each` and use below modification

```
$('.page-breadcrumb').children('li').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).children().find('span.Title').text();
    if(txt != '')
      v.push(txt);
});

PushState = v.join('/');
```

Comment: A perfect solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Target the selector you want in the event listener:

Change

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
```

To

```
$(document).on('click','.page-breadcrumb a' function(e) {
     // "this" will be instance of .page-breadcrumb a
     var spanText = $(this).find('.Title').text()
     .....
```